# How to solve this homework logic?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my challenge:

> Write a function which takes a string input and returns a function. The returned function should print characters of the string one at a time and in a loop.
>
> ```
> var xyz = MyFunction('xyz');
> xyz(); // should return 'x' on this first call
> xyz(); // should return 'y' on this second call
> xyz(); // should return 'z' on this third call
> xyz(); // should return 'x' again on this fourth call
> ```

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var xyz = 'xzy';
  myFunction(xyz);
}

function myFunction(xyz) {
  var text = xyz;
  var arr = text.split('');
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (i === 3) {
      continue;
    }
    text = arr[i];
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: _please help me this..._ Help you on what?

Comment: its show me only y value :(

Comment: Were you taught about generators? If not, it's fine, it's an advanced topic. Okay, First of all, your function is not doing what the task tells you it should: for one thing, it is not returning a function. Start there. Try to write a function that returns a function, even if it isn't doing anything yet. You can do it by editing the question and appending to it. This function will have access to the parameters of `myFunction` because it will be a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming\)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question never asked for generators, but JavaScript it's really easy to create a function that returns a function, added to this you can use closures to capture state.

eg.

```js
function MyFunction (input) {
  var char_pos = 0;
  return function () {
    return input[char_pos++ % input.length];
  }
}


var xyz = MyFunction('xyz');
console.log(xyz()); // should return 'x' on this first call
console.log(xyz()); // should return 'y' on this second call
console.log(xyz()); // should return 'z' on this third call
console.log(xyz()); // should return 'x' again on this fourth call
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var s = "overpopulation";
  for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    document.write(s.charAt(i) + '<br/>');
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Why include jquery if you don’t even use it? Also this just writes out each char from the string on a new line it doesn’t loop back round and it’s not in the form of a stateful function.